# Return multiple model records with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there an elegant way to return multiple model records in Rails saved as local variables using includes? I was thinking it would look something like this, just trying to get the syntax down. flight_passengers belong to flights, flights have_many flight_passengers.

```
flights, flight_passengers = Flight.where(date: params[:date]).includes(:flight_passengers)
```

The data would be passed back to the react/redux client as a JSON response.

Comment: If you do that you'll lose the association, why don't you render the flight_passengers inside the flight json? that makes more sense than splitting the objects into two different collections

Comment: Ah so if I rendered the following `flights = Flight.where(date: params[:date]).includes(:flight_passengers)` as json, it would include the flight_passengers data? FYI - we use jbuilders to format the responses, so we've been in the habit of splitting into different collections.

Comment: Check the jbuilder docs https://github.com/rails/jbuilder, you can do `json.flight_passengers flight.flight_passengers ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# includes is used to avoid n+1 query.  
@flights = Flight.where(date: params[:date]).includes(:flight_passengers)
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @flights.as_json(:include => [:flight_passengers]) }
end
```

For more reference [Read this...](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

Comment: ok great, did not realize I needed the include statement in the response as well. Thanks.